# How can I initialize a sequence in F# with existing items?

Tags: f#, sequence

In C#, you can initialize a list like so:

```
var list = new List<int> { obj1, obj2, obj3 };
```

I was expecting to do something similar in F# but keep getting errors:

```
let list =  { obj1, obj2, obj3 }
```

Is this possible in F#?

Comment: The [Lists (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx) page on MSDN has a bunch of examples.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To create an (immutable) F# list, you can write:

```
let list = [ obj1; obj2; obj3 ]
```

There is a number of other options. You can create arrays by using `[| .. |]` instead of `[ .. ]` and you can also write sequence expressions that allow you to generate data - similarly to C# iterator methods. For more information, refer to:

- [Sequences at F# WikiBook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Sequences)
- [Sequences (F#) at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx)

Comment: I was trying to get a sequence, but this worked since the method I was passing it into was expecting an IEnumerable. Do you know how to init a Seq?

Comment: @JoshuaBelden - you can just do `[obj1;obj2;obj3]:>Seq<_>` - As `Seq` is an interface I don't think that this sort of `Seq` literal is supported

Comment: Ahh! Grok! I was thinking [] was array and seq was directly related to System.Collections.Generic.List<T>. Seq is an alias for IEnumerable<T>. List was what I was looking for, and that's why I could pass it to my method that expected IEnumerable<T>. The cast would be extraneous. Thank you gentleman, much appreciated. Tom, great book so far.

Comment: @JoshuaBelden Thanks! Another way to construct `IEnumerable<T>` (or `seq<T>`) is to use built-in function named `seq`, so you can write e.g. `seq [1;2;3]` (which just creates a list and casts it)